# Book about the son of a star traveller who is raised by low tech people but runs away

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

A sequel to a book about a star traveler, this 60-70's American SF paperback I got from my mom's collection is about his son who is hairier than the low tech people he is raised by. Compared to his fellow tribe members, the boy was shorter, broader, stronger, and definitely hairier. The puberty fairies hit him hard in the hirsute department and went back for more. When he tired of his peer's teasing, he packed and left through the desert, where he was caught by bandits who beat, robbed, & by implication, molested him. He woke with nothing except his loincloth that had been used to wipe someone's ass. After wiping it clean-ish on the sand he was dying of thirst & sunstroke when a storm transformed the desert with a lovingly described procession of once dormant life that sustained him in a spasm of activity until ready to go quiescent when the water dried up again. He was down to the now hallucinogenic cacti he was using for food and drink, when he tripped out, but by now he was on the verge of a forested region. It was there he met the Winged People, and the human girl who was tagging along with them. The high tech winged people carry a sentient amorphous symbiote in their bodies that hold memories. The leader sits back to back with the protagonist and shares his symbiote with him. I didn't read the first book, but got the impression that dad ascended somehow? While I do own it, I've misplaced it and want to get it on Kindle.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When and where did you read this book?  Check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/101407) for good story-id questions to see if they help you recall any additional details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Maybe you're misremembering something? Instead of "hairier", do you think maybe the protagonist has differently colored hair than the people around him? I am thinking of a specific Andre Norton work from the 50's.

Comment: No, you're thinking of Star Man's Son, aka Daybreak 2250 A.D. This was at least a decade later.